# Server 2008 2 Nics one internal network, one gets an ip the other doesn't

Tags: windows-server-2008

I have a feeling this is pretty obvious but I can't figure it out.

I have a Server 2008 (No Hyper-V) installed with dual NICs, both on the internal network.

One identifies with the domain fine and gets an IP, the other does not. Assigning a static IP doesn't help and I can't ping it when I do assign a static IP.

The 2nd NIC was added after the 2008 setup and initial install but has all the correct drivers. Any clues?

Answer (score 1):

1. Faulty NIC
2. The switch it's connected to is locked down to only serve white-listed MAC addresses

Ways to test both of them: Plug the NIC into something else, either directly into another computer (eg laptop), or into dumb switch, and manually configure the IP addresses and see if you can talk directly to the other computer.

Pinging is often not a good test of network connectivity though as ICMP packets could be blocked for whatever reason.

Comment: 3. The NIC doesn't have a cable plugged into it, or the cable is bad.